# Bind to template of formly field on click of other field in angular formly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-formly

I have been using a formly form that has a section in which I display dynamic HTML, I made use of the template field in which I am initializing HTML on load. When I click the other field value I need to change this HTML however the value change is assigned but not reflected in HTML UI, I have created stackblitz example for the scenario:

[Stackblitz Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formly-example-uqzopj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Please find below code snippet :

**Initialized HTML value is following:**

```
htmlValue = '<p>test</p>';
```

**Field value assigned:**

```
{ template : this.htmlValue }
```

**On click of submit button assigned HTML should be expected output:**

> this.htmlValue = `

```
          <p class="mb-2"><b>Maximum  Spend Per Cricketer:</b></p>
          <div class="alert alert-secondary border flex-column mb-0">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">Snacks:</div>
              <div class="col">$15.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">Breakfast:</div>
              <div class="col">$25.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">Lunch:</div>
              <div class="col">$45.00</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;
```

**How can I achieve this output?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use a simple code to explain your problem

```js
let a = 4;
let b = {a}
a= 8;

console.log({a})
console.log({b})
```

Its a simple explanatory, you changed a but b didn't change. Same to your case, you have changed `htmlValue` but `fields` is not changed. A simple way to solve this would be to use a getter

```
  get fields(): FormlyFieldConfig[] {
    return [
      {
        key: "header",
        type: "input",
        templateOptions: {
          type: "text",
          label: "Page Header",
          placeholder: "Enter page header",
          required: true
        }
      },
      {
        template: this.htmlValue
      }
    ];
  }
```

With a getter, whenever the value of `htmlValue` changes, the value of fields would change

### Edit

Another option would be to simply change the value of the template section in four formly object

```typescript
this.fields[1].template = this.htmlValue;
```

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formly-example-yh7jcm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for clearing the concept and providing the solution but in my case, I cannot apply a getter to the entire FormlyFieldConfig so can there be an alternative with accessing the field of formly and setting it.

Comment: Thank you Owen for providing the explanation and the demo examples, this helped me to understand the setting of a field value and the importance of getter